# How to get result from Asynctask in viewHolder?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to set text different according to `AsyncTask` result in `ViewHolder` item from `Adapter` class.
This is my `ViewHolder` class.
So how to get result from `AsyncTask` and change data in `ViewHolder` item?

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_TV);
        }
    }

title .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   if (receiverAudioMessageButton.getTag().equals("download"))
                   {
                      new DownloadAudioFromURL().execute(params);
                     //here i want to get result true or false from asynctask
                     // if asynctask==true...do something;
                     // else...do something;
                     // notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition);

                   }

                 }
           });
```

`AsyncTask` class:

```
private class DownloadAudioFromURL extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, MyTaskParams, Boolean> {
     protected Boolean doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {

     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isDownload) {
         if (isDownload)
        {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Audio Downloaded Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
           Toast.makeText(mContext, "Audio Not Downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     }
 }
```